# Mock animate function in react-testing-library / jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I am using [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) function to animate height of a div. The code looks like this and happens in `useLayoutEffect` :

```
      const animation = ref.current.animate(
        { height: [oldHeight, newHeight] },
        { duration: 100 }
      );
```

And my component JSX looks like :

```
 return (
  <div ref={ref}> {children} </div>
)
```

But during testing with `react-testing-library` I get the error `ref.current.animate` is not a function. I confirmed that `ref.current` is defined. How can we mock this function with `Jest` . Went through Jest documentation on mocking functions , window object etc but couldn't find info on how to mock these functions on dom nodes.

Comment: How did you confirmed that `ref.current` is defined?

Comment: @badal saibo just did a console.log and i also have an `if` check

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What test result did you get? What do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up mocking as :

```
const animationMock = () => {
  type Animate = {
    (
      keyframes: Keyframe[] | PropertyIndexedKeyframes | null,
      options?: number | KeyframeAnimationOptions | undefined
    ): Animation;
    (
      keyframes: Keyframe[] | PropertyIndexedKeyframes | null,
      options?: number | KeyframeAnimationOptions | undefined
    ): Animation;
  };

  let originalAnimateFunction: Animate;

  // Mock native animate function
  beforeAll(() => {
    originalAnimateFunction = HTMLDivElement.prototype.animate;

    const obj = {
      onfinish: () => {},
    };

    const animationFunction = function (this: any) {
      Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
        act(() => obj.onfinish());
      });

      return obj as unknown as Animation;
    };

    HTMLDivElement.prototype.animate = animationFunction;
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    HTMLDivElement.prototype.animate = originalAnimateFunction;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

add in your mock file :

```
jest.mock("animejs/lib/anime.es", () => jest.fn())
```

and don't forget you call your mock file in jest configuration file

```
"setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/configuration/__mocks__/jest.mock.js"
],
```